# Simple HTML/CSS crossbrowser solution to float nested html tag left and parent to the right

Tags: html, css

I have following html:

```
<div class="text_right">
    <p>Hello World
        <a target="_blank" href="/some/url">
            <img class="image_right" alt="Fruits" src="http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/9/91/Get-the-URL-for-Pictures-Step-1.jpg/670px-Get-the-URL-for-Pictures-Step-1.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to be able show `img` as `float:left` and "Hello World" text as `float-right` on the same line

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFE5R/)

Comment: So the image on the left side and "Hello World" on the right. Correct?

Comment: And why is the image in the paragraph?

Comment: @Shrink correct...I am unable to get the image on left and text on right...if they were 2 separate divs should look like image was floated left and text was floated right

Comment: unfortunately I cannot change the text coming from backend...I am a noob with html css and I am not even sure if this can be done

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/jazoronu/1/edit

Comment: I dont  think its on same line

Comment: Since its an image all you do is play around with the height

Comment: What is the issue with just floating the image left? http://jsfiddle.net/AFE5R/8/

Comment: @dwreck08 that looks good...but the text does not have `float:right` effect...you can pull up firebug and inspect text..

Comment: Do you have the option for a div wrap around the text and floating that? http://jsfiddle.net/AFE5R/9/

Comment: @dwreck08 thanks for pursuing...unfortunately not an option :( ...its being laid out by backend that I do not have any control over

Comment: Do you find the solution? If so, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Beterraba ok I did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking a bit around here is what fixed it:

```
p{
    text-align: right;
}

a {
    float: left;
}
```